# values couldnot pass from controller to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My controller code is

path to : application/views/admin
[image]

controller code

```
public function email()
{
    $data['page'] = lang('settings');
    $data['load_setting'] = 'email_settings';
    $data['title'] = lang('email_settings'); //Page title              
    $data['subview'] = $this->load->view('admin/settings/settings', $data, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data); //page load     
    $qry = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_email_setting` WHERE user_id='".$this->session->userdata('user_id')."'");
    $data1['email_values'] = $qry->result_array();      
    $this->load->view('admin/settings/email_settings', $data1);
}
```

I am passing `$data1` to `email_settings.php` file in views.
when I am trying to print `$email_values` in `views/admin/settings/email_settings.php`, error is coming as below

> PHP Error was encountered
>     Severity: Notice
>     Message: Undefined variable: email_values
>     Filename: settings/email_settings.php
>     Line Number: 109

Comment: `print_r($data1['email_values'])` first chk this

Comment: or just simply pass this `$data1['email_values'] = "test";`

Comment: as I know only index of an array we will get on views...Right?

Comment: PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data1

Filename: settings/email_settings.php

Line Number: 109

Comment: Could you please share your view code if possible?

Comment: chk this `print_r($data1);` in your controller, also show your view part, where you are calling it

Comment: First step to debug would be in controller, check if the index is actually getting set, then check in your view file

Comment: this is view code what I m printing

 <?php echo 'email server type:-----';print_r($data1['email_values']);?>

Comment: dont know y r u using twice `$this->load->view`, you can store first view in a variable, than print in last `$this->load->view`

Comment: You should print $email_values instead of $data1['email_values'];

Comment: ohh man, this will work as `print_r($email_values)`

Comment: when I m printing $data1 in controller , showing required data from database.

Comment: Post your code to get any help from here,also please try to refer codeigniter docs to know the syntax.

Comment: "<?php echo 'email server type:-----';print_r($email_values);?>"
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <label>IMAP</label>
                <input type="radio"  class="email" value="imap" name="email_server" required <?php //if(@$email_settings[0]['email_server_type'] == 'pop3') echo $check = 'checked="checked"';?>>
                <label>POP3</label>
                <input type="radio" required class="email" value="pop3" name="email_server" <?php //if(@$email_settings[0]['email_server_type'] == 'imap') echo $check = 'checked="checked"';?>>
              </di

Comment: add code in your question or read the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments:

*this is view code what I m printing `<?php echo 'email server type:-----';print_r($data1['email_values']);?>` – R V Informatics Pvt Ltd*

You just need to print data in view file as:

```
<?php 
echo 'email server type:-----';
print_r($email_values);
?>
```

**Suggestion / Side note:**

I suggest you to store this view in a variable:

```
$this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data); //page load
```

**Same like this:**

```
$data['subview'] = $this->load->view('admin/settings/settings', $data, TRUE);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend,
your solution is now working fine.

thanks a lot.